# What is needed for .on('init') to work on an ember component?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to run some code every time an ember component is used.

Sample that doesn't work:

```
App.GdRadioInput = Em.Component.extend({
    setupFlags: function(){
        console.log('contentString');
    }.on("init")
});
```

Sample calling the component (the component get's initalized):

```
{{Gd-radio-input contentString="asdf"key="asdf"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `Component` in the end. Just update to the following and will work:

```
App.GdRadioInputComponent = Em.Component.extend({
    setupFlags: function(){
        console.log('contentString');
    }.on("init")
});
```

Comment: I'm going to kill myself now.

Comment: Haha. Sometime ago that problem made me crazy too.